# segue enable Rotation

Tags: ios, xcode

Can any one help, the code below works from the portrait view when the app starts, if i rotate to landscape if works great and shows the new view, but when rotate back to portrait, instead of getting the original view, I just get a crash, many thanks

`

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
     {
     [super viewDidAppear:animated];

     [self enableRotation];

     }

     - (void)didRotate
    {
    [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
    if ([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
    [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) {

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"segueToNumbers"sender: self];

    }

     else if ([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait ||
         [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown){

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"segueToChoose"sender: self];

    }

    }


     - (void)enableRotation
    {
   [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didRotate)
                                             name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                                           object:nil];
   }
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Do not respond to rotation events. You need to design you UI with AutoLayout to adjust to different screen size. in iOS 8 the orientation is irrelevant, your code should consider size classes instead

Comment: Thank you for the response, I am using a portrait view to select the criteria and then rotate the iPhone to landscape to view the results, I am using Main.storyboard with two viewcontollers & would like to rotate the phone to move forward and back, I did it in earlier Xcode with nibs, but struggling with Main.storyboard

Comment: I'm not sure why your UI won't show results in portrait as well, but as long as your project supports landscape mode, you don't need to write any code to allow your view controller to rotate